# Connect to MDB from java jar File - Failure

Tags: java, database, jar, odbc

I have a java program connecting to a mdb database file. In Eclipse it works fine. Now I export the program as an jar file. When I start the program now and want to have access to the same file, I get the message

> Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

I have already registered the database as ODBC-source in windows, but it doesn't work. The Path to the Database is the same in Eclipse and in jar. Maybe is the problem accessing some external source from within a jar?? Any suggestions?

```
protected static Connection getAccessConnection(String fullPath)
  throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException 
  {
    String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
    Class.forName(driver);      
    String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver="
         + "{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};"
         + "DBQ="
         + fullPath.replace("\\", "/");
    String username = "";
    String password = "";
    Connection result =
        DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: why do you need path to db when using odbc ?

Comment: i'm using  Connection result = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password); in java to connect to the database, with url = jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:/xx/xx/Desktop/gfs-tmp/DB5.MDB

Comment: Can you try with this simple code Connection result = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:<name-of-the-dsn>",,); and see if it works

Comment: it works, yes thanks, but it does not solve my problem. the program shall work on every machine, not only on those on which i registered the mdb file and accessed it with the name of the dsn-> therefore i used jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:/xx/xx/Desktop/gfs-tmp/DB5.MDB 

->Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb) should be available on the systems, and DBQ the path to my selected mdb file.

-> like mentioned, it works FINE in Eclipse, but not in an external jar file...

Comment: can you pl save the db at the root folder meaning c: or d:

Comment: Can you modify your question and show as both code with connect string and error message?

Comment: I saved the db at the root, no cure... Why does it work in Eclipse but not as a jar?

Comment: This guy had the same problem: http://www.java-forums.org/jdbc/27142-issue-ms-access-database-jar.html

Comment: You can also show us what version of OS you use, and what version of Java
(maybe your application in form of `.jar` is used by 64-bit Java while Eclipse use 32 bit Java?)

Comment: ... thx @Michal Niklas! So i have Windows 7 64 with jre 64 installed. However, in Eclipse i set my installed jre to the buildpath as jre system library. How can is check if eclipse use 32 bit java?

Comment: 32 and 64 bit connect strings Access differ a little, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you use different versions of Java: 64 bit in `.jar` mode and 32 bit in Eclipse mode. You can check this using ProcessExpliorer or other similar tool. According to: http://www.selikoff.net/2011/07/26/connecting-to-ms-access-file-via-jdbc-in-64-bit-java/

is seems that connect string to Access database is different for 32 and 64 bit environments. In 32 bit you can use:

```
jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};...
```

In 64 bit:

```
jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};...
```

I think you can try both and use first that work (throw exception if both do not work). This way your application will be able to work in both 32 bit and 64 bit JRE.

If you use the same JRE in both Eclipse and `.jar`:

In ODBC administrator there is "Tracing" tab. Enable tracing and run your application from Eclipse. Save this trace log and then make trace log from `.jar` application. Compare both traces.